# Snapchat API Error: "The start time should be start of a Local Time Zone day for DAY query."

Tags: api, timestamp-with-timezone, snapchat

I am making following request for Snapchat API:

```
GET https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/ads/7e4ebe9a-f903-4849-bd46-c590dbb4345e/stats?
granularity=DAY
&fields=android_installs,attachment_avg_view_time_millis,attachment_impressions,attachment_quartile_1,attachment_quartile_2,attachment_quartile_3,attachment_total_view_time_millis,attachment_view_completion,avg_screen_time_millis,avg_view_time_millis,impressions,ios_installs,quartile_1,quartile_2,quartile_3,screen_time_millis,spend,swipe_up_percent,swipes,total_installs,video_views,view_completion,view_time_millis,conversion_purchases,conversion_purchases_value,conversion_save,conversion_start_checkout,conversion_add_cart,conversion_view_content,conversion_add_billing,conversion_searches,conversion_level_completes,conversion_app_opens,conversion_page_views,attachment_frequency,attachment_uniques,frequency,uniques,story_opens,story_completes,conversion_sign_ups,total_installs_swipe_up,android_installs_swipe_up,ios_installs_swipe_up,conversion_purchases_swipe_up,conversion_purchases_value_swipe_up,conversion_save_swipe_up,conversion_start_checkout_swipe_up,conversion_add_cart_swipe_up,conversion_view_content_swipe_up,conversion_add_billing_swipe_up,conversion_sign_ups_swipe_up,conversion_searches_swipe_up,conversion_level_completes_swipe_up,conversion_app_opens_swipe_up,conversion_page_views_swipe_up,total_installs_view,android_installs_view,ios_installs_view,conversion_purchases_view,conversion_purchases_value_view,conversion_save_view,conversion_start_checkout_view,conversion_add_cart_view,conversion_view_content_view,conversion_add_billing_view,conversion_sign_ups_view,conversion_searches_view,conversion_level_completes_view,conversion_app_opens_view,conversion_page_views_view
&swipe_up_attribution_window=28_DAY
&view_attribution_window=1_DAY
&start_time=2018-10-05T00:00:00.000-08:00
&end_time=2018-10-19T00:00:00.000-08:00
```

Getting following Error:

```
 {
    "request_status": "ERROR",
    "request_id": "5bf3f47e00ff060ab0faf7f4330001737e616473617069736300016275696c642d30666635373463642d312d3232302d350001010c",
    "debug_message": "The start time should be start of a Local Time Zone day for DAY query.",
    "display_message": "We're sorry, but the data provided in the request is incomplete or incorrect",
    "error_code": "E1008"
}
```

Certain date ranges will work and others won't. It also doesn't matter what timezone offset (Europe/London +00:00, Los Angeles, -08:00) I use or how I format the request dates (2018-10-01T00:00:00Z, 2018-10-01T00:00:00.000, 2018-10-01T00:00:00.000-08:00, etc) for the ad stats request date range, the error will come back the same. The error has a code but it's not detailed in Snapchat's documentation. All they say is "it's a bad request".

For example, one ad would let me query 29/10/2018 to date or even 29/10/2018 to 30/10/2018 but as soon as I change it to 28/10/2018, it fails with the same error.

There's no apparent start/end times on ads as I thought it might be related to that. It's also not related to the campaign start/end times in this one case we tested.

API DOC: https://developers.snapchat.com/api/docs/?shell#overview

Comment: Just to verify that you have URL encoded your parameters when making your request?  The `start_time` and `end_time` params do not look URL encoded in your request.

Comment: Hey @MartinParkin, I have tried URL encoded request as well. Still same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue with above error. I forgot to consider the day light saving while passing the timezone offset.

For e.g. We need to check if there is day light saving for the start_time or end_time and adjust the offset accordingly for that timezone.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please? Like if you are in timezone +01:00 and both start_time and end_time is in that time zone without DST - what do you input then?